# Found 'module' keyword inside a module before the 'endmodule'

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I am working on a simple cpu with a register in system verilog as follows:

```
module register(
input clk, e,
input [7:0]in,
output reg [7:0]out
);

always@(posedge clk or posedge e)
begin
    if(e == 1)
        out <= in;
    else
        out <= out; 
end
endmodule
```

When I compile everything, I get the following errors:

```
Error-[USVSNM] Unsupported System Verilog construct
register.v, 1
lm2
Found 'module' keyword inside a module before the 'endmodule'. Nested 
modules are not supported.


Error-[SE] Syntax error
Following verilog source has syntax error :
"register.v", 2: token is 'input'
input clk, e,
           ^
```

I'm scratching my head on this one. I only see module declared once, and I don't see anything wrong with my syntax. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You say SystemVerilog, but you are not using an SV constructs. `register` is written in Verilog-2001.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that somewhere in your design there is something like the following:

```
module upper_module;
// ...
`include "register.v"
// ...
endmoudle
```

This would create a *nested module*. To fix it, move the `` `include `` line above `module` or below `endmodule`.

Technically *nested modules* are part of SystemVerilog (see IEEE Std 1800-2005 § 19.6 *Nested modules* & [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 23.4 *Nested modules*), however may vendors have not implemented this feature.

---

FYI: `or posedge e` shouldn't be there. Synchronous logic should be a edged clock and zero to two async resets, where the async reset assigns the flop(s) to a content.

Comment: That was it! It was included in another module above the module declaration, but that module was included in another module, hence the issue. Thank you! Also, thank you for the input regarding the logic, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: One more thing that may have caused it. I commented out an endmodule statement in one of my modules, so it saw a module within a module. Thanks again!